# Show that the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle is $\ge$ the length of a leg.

Tags: plane-geometry

This question is in chapter 5 $\S$3 of Serge Lang's Basic Mathematics.

Am I wrong in thinking there is no right triangle that exists such that the length of the hypotenuse is equal to the length of a leg? It seems to me that for a right triangle, the length of the hypotenuse will always be greater than the length of a leg, but never equal.

Comment: Hint: Euclid's [Book I Proposition 19](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI19.html): "*in any triangle the side opposite the greater angle is greater*".

Comment: It's equal if at least one in $a$ or $b$ is $0$.

Comment: @dxiv I don't understand how your comment answers josh's question, perhaps the title of this question should be edited as josh is interested in the equality in the statement.

Comment: @CedricMartens In any right triangle, the right angle is the largest angle, so the hypotenuse is the largest side. Note that a degenerate triangle with a side equal to zero is not customarily called a right triangle.

Comment: Is this question all about why Lang didn't say $>$ instead of $\ge$? Maybe because he doesn't need a stronger statement? Maybe because he considers degenerate triangles (those with side $0$) as well? Maybe because he has not developed the necessary tools to derive the stricter inequality by that point? I don't have the book at hand, so I really don't know - but you are right: in (what we commonly call) a right triangle, the inequality _will_ be strict.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, my question is indeed about why Lang wrote $\ge$ instead of $>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equality can happen in degenerate triangle. However, it wouldn't be a right triangle anymore.

By the pythagorean theorem,

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$$

If $a=0$ or $b=0$, then it is the case that the hypothenuse is the same length as a leg.

So it only is true, if we include degenerate triangles.

In the case that $a$ and $b$ must be positive, then $c^2$ is greater than $a^2$ or $b^2$.

Suppose that $c^2$ = $a^2$,

By definition, we know that $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$, and since $b^2$ is non-zero then $a^2 \lt a^2 + b^2$, meaning that $c^2$ cannot be equal to $a^2$. The same argument applies to $b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

By the Pythagorean Theorem, we know if a right triangle has legs of length $a,b$, then it's hypotenous has length
$$
c:=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.
$$
Since these lengths $a,b$ are both positive, as they connect two distinct points in a plane, it follows that
$$
c > \sqrt{\max\{a^2,b^2\}} = max\{a,b\}.
$$

Hope this help. Thanks for the awesome question! :D

Comment: This answers the question of the title but not the question that OP had